# Add a class to <ul> html tag on Woocommerce shop and archive pages

Tags: php, html, wordpress, templates, woocommerce

Somewhere in the html of my Woocommerce shop page I have this line:

```
<ul class="products columns-3">`
```

I'd simply like to add the bootstrap class "row" to it like:

```
<ul class="products columns-3 row">
```

I inserted the bootstrap cdn in my chrome elements tool then added the "row" and I have the result I want it but I can't find in my website files where to change it.

I know the html code is generated by `functions.php`, I tried to look down in almost every php page on templates and woocommerce. Can someone explain me how this can be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To **add a custom class** to `<ul>` html tag on WooCommerce shop and archives pages:

1. First read ["Overriding templates via a theme"](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/) official documentation, that explains you how to override woocommerce templates via a theme.

   **Note** for "Premium Themes": 
   On some premium themes, they can use already some customized WooCommerce templates, so you will have to use them instead. If you are using a child theme with it, copy the related template to your child theme, respecting the same folder hierarchy.
2. Once understood this, the related template to edit is `loop/loop-start.php`.
    
   Open/edit it and replace:

   ```
   <ul class="products columns-<?php echo esc_attr( wc_get_loop_prop( 'columns' ) ); ?>">
   ```

   with:

   ```
   <ul class="products columns-<?php echo esc_attr( wc_get_loop_prop( 'columns' ) ); ?> row">
   ```
3. Save… You are done.